# C: Array element availability discrepancy?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

So, I uncovered a "discrepancy"--or, more likely, a gap in my understanding of arrays in C. Below is a trivial program to reverse strings. The discrepancy is noted within the code's comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverser(char to_bb[]){
    printf("%s\n", to_bb[some_valid_number]); /* This results in a bus error */
    int counter = strlen(to_bb);              /* ^ Assume actual integer */
    char reversed[counter];         
    int counter2 = 0;
    for(--counter; counter >= 0; counter--){     
        reversed[counter2] = to_bb[counter];  /* This does not */
        counter2++;
    }
    reversed[counter2] = '\0';
    printf("The reversed: %s\n", reversed);
}

int main(){
    char to_be_reversed[20];
    puts("Enter the string to be reversed: ");
    scanf("%19s", to_be_reversed);
    reverser(to_be_reversed);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `printf();` result in a bus error, while calling the elements to swap them into a different array does not? Aren't they calling the same thing?

Comment: Passing in an incompatible argument to `printf` isn't a good thing to do.

Comment: @H2CO3 According to my output it will be!

Comment: @d0rmLife Oh, well, it will. You haven't made the typical beginner mistake, sorry for the prejudice :P

Comment: @H2CO3 Don't worry, I'm still a beginner... for now! >:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
printf("%s\n", to_bb[some_valid_number]);
```

`s` conversion specifier requires a pointer to `char` but `to_bb[some_valid_number]` is of type `char`.

To get a pointer to `to_bb[some_valid_number]` object you can use the `&` operator:

```
printf("%s\n", &to_bb[some_valid_number]);
```

If instead you want to print the `to_bb[some_valid_number]` character, use the `c` conversion specifier:

```
printf("%c\n", to_bb[some_valid_number]);
```

Comment: Do I have to create a pointer to `to_bb[some_valid_number]` or is there a different way to specify this in `printf();`?

Comment: @d0rmLife Please RTFM (Read the Formatted I/O Manual). `%c` is what you're looking for (and a good tutorial on arrays and pointers).

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for the F$%^ing manual... it can be comically difficult to discover such obvious resources as a beginner! Thanks again

Comment: `&to_bb[some_valid_number]` is same as `to_bb + some_valid_number`

Comment: @d0rmLife chars are just variables, there is no such thing as strings, just arrays or chars. So when you need one char, you can use it's value directly or it's address to get the value. But for strings, you have to use the address of the first one, so you can jump to the next one and next and next untill you reach \0. (I'm using words pointer and address interchangeably here). (You can also think of arrays as pointers, for a beginner it's a justifiable simplification)

Comment: Hey people, come on, can't we get "ouah" an Enlightened badge? :D